# Why do I recieve 'TypeError: 'module' object is not callable' for scipy.integrate._quadrature?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

So I am quite a novice at coding. I'm following a reader from my prof, however sometimes the reader is not updated. The code below was first implemented for scipy.integrate.quadrature I first received an error that the module did not exist so I found that it was now named "scipy.integrate._quadrature".

However, now the code has difficulty with my defined function "func(x)". Does this mean I have to implement the equation I wish to integrate directly into the _quadrature module? As follows: quad(x*np.sin(x), a, b). If so how would I define x then?

Thanks in advance! I really appreciate your help.

```
import math 
import scipy.integrate._quadrature as quad         

def func(x):
    return x*np.sin(x)

def exactIntegral(a, b):
    Iab = -b*np.cos(b) + np.sin(b) + a*np.cos(b) - np.sin(a)
    return Iab

a = 0.0
b = 2.0 

exact = exactIntegral(a, b)
estimate = quad(func, a, b)                               #TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

print('Exact %1.6f Numerical %1.6f' %(exact, estimate[0]))
print('Error %1.3e' % np.abs(exact-estimate[0]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate 
[..] 
estimate = integrate.quadrature(func, a, b)
```

*_quadrature* is not a function but a file/module that contains the function you are looking for. The *scipy.integrate* module contains what you are looking for.